# Why does curl not return any response inside a while loop in bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

I have trouble getting curl to return a response. When I comment out the while loop or when I pass in a hardcoded URL, curl works perfectly. As you can see in the code below, curl does not work and displays an error "curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL". I suspect that `"${REQUEST_STR}"` is the problem. Does anyone know a correct way to pass a string variable to curl? Thank you so much.

```
while read -r POS_SN
do
    # echo "${POS_SN}"
    REQUEST_STR="${BASE_URL}?usercode=${USER_CODE}&userpass=${USER_PASS}&sn=${POS_SN}"

    echo "Request: ${REQUEST_STR}"
    echo "Response: "
    curl  "${REQUEST_STR}"

done < "$input"
```

**SOLUTION:** I added `IFS=$'\r'` to the line `while IFS=$\'r' read -r POS_SN` and now curl works perfectly. I'm still not sure why it works but it works :)

Comment: Are your BASE_URL, USER_CODE, and USER_PASS variables set properly?  You can also try executing your script via bash -x for more debug information.   https://www.shellcheck.net/ is also a great tool for debugging common bash issues.

Comment: Check your file for carriage returns

Comment: You have an `echo "Request: ${REQUEST_STR}"`. Did you try ` curl "${REQUEST_STR}"`  from the commandline?

Comment: @notClickBait: From the error message, I wuld conclude that `BASE_URL` is not set properly. Did you try to run the code with ´-x`?

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following should probably work for you assuming you set the `base_url`, `user_code`, and `user_pass` variables according to your needs:

```
#!/bin/bash

base_url="https://www.google.com"
user_code="some_user_code"
user_pass="some_user_pass"


while read -r pos_sn
do
    echo "${pos_sn}"
    url="${base_url}?usercode=${user_code}&userpass=${user_pass}&sn=${pos_sn}"

    echo "Request: ${url}"
    echo "Response: "
    curl "${url}"

done
```